# why does it throw an error when i compile it?

Tags: c++

In **index.hpp** I have created a class that has multiple data members like `int age`, `std::string city;` etc. i have defined a constructor outside the class. In **program.cpp** i have created an object called sam. when i try to compile it, it shows error. what's the reason?

**program.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "index.hpp"

int main(){
  profile sam("Sam Drakkila", 30, "New York", "USA", "he/him");
  std::cout<<sam.name;
}
```

**index.hpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class profile{

public:
    std::string name;
  int age;
  std::string city;
  std::string country;
  std::string pronouns;
  std::vector<std::string> hobbies;

};
profile::profile(std::string new_name, int new_age,std::string 
        new_city,std::string new_country, std::string 
         new_pronouns = "they/them"){
 name = new_name;
 age = new_age;
 city = new_city;
 country = new_country;
 pronouns = new_pronouns;
         }
```

**error message**

```
In file included from program.cpp:2:0:
index.hpp:15:1: error: prototype for 'profile::profile(std::__cxx11::string, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)' does not match any in class 'profile'
 profile::profile(std::string new_name, int new_age,std::string
 ^~~~~~~
index.hpp:4:7: error: candidates are: profile::profile(profile&&)
 class profile{
       ^~~~~~~
index.hpp:4:7: error:                 profile::profile(const profile&)
index.hpp:4:7: error:                 profile::profile()
program.cpp: In function 'int main()':
program.cpp:5:62: error: no matching function for call to 'profile::profile(const char [13], int, const char [9], const char [4], const char [7])'
   profile sam("Sam Drakkila", 30, "New York", "USA", "he/him");
                                                              ^
In file included from program.cpp:2:0:
index.hpp:4:7: note: candidate: profile::profile()
 class profile{
       ^~~~~~~
index.hpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 5 provided
index.hpp:4:7: note: candidate: profile::profile(const profile&)
index.hpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided
index.hpp:4:7: note: candidate: profile::profile(profile&&)
index.hpp:4:7: note: candidate: profile::profile(const profile&)
index.hpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided
index.hpp:4:7: note: candidate: profile::profile(profile&&)
index.hpp:4:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 5 provided
 .\index }
index.hpp:15:1: error: prototype for 'profile::profile(std::__cxx11::string, int, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)' does not match any in class 'profile'
 profile::profile(std::string new_name, int new_age,std::string
 ^~~~~~~
index.hpp:4:7: error: candidates are: profile::profile(profile&&)
 class profile{
       ^~~~~~~
index.hpp:4:7: error:                 profile::profile(const profile&)
index.hpp:4:7: error:                 profile::profile()
```

Comment: Because you attempt to define (and use) a constructor that has not been declared. I guess it's just a misplaced closing `}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have defined a constructor outside the class

Yes, but you have not declared it inside the class.
Also, you should not put code inside header files unless you are creating a template.

To fix your problem, add the declaration to the class:

```
class profile{

public:
    profile(std::string new_name, int new_age, std::string new_city, std::string new_country, std::string new_pronouns);

    std::string name;
    int age;
    std::string city;
    std::string country;
    std::string pronouns;
    std::vector<std::string> hobbies;
};
```

You should also consider moving the code of the constructor to index.cpp, and renaming the files profile.hpp and profile.cpp for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the constructor inside the class definition:

```
class profile{

public:
    std::string name;
  int age;
  std::string city;
  std::string country;
  std::string pronouns;
  std::vector<std::string> hobbies;
  profile::profile(std::string new_name, int new_age,std::string 
        new_city,std::string new_country, std::string 
         new_pronouns = "they/them");
};
```

As a side note: you should prefer a [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) for the task done by the constructor.